# My page freezes when sending an ajax post request with a datatype of html

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this ajax post script.

```
$('#pagesfilter a').click(function(e){
    var realname = $(this).attr("data-realname");
     $.ajax({
       url: "/ajaxpage",
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "html",
       data: { page: $(this).attr('data-page') },
       //cache: false,
       async:true,
       beforeSend: function() { //show loading animation 
            $('.whiteblur').show();
            $('.windows8').show();
         },
         complete: function(){ //hide loading animation
            $('.windows8').hide();
            $('.whiteblur').hide();
         },
       success: function(data){ //display the requested page
          $("#main_content_wrapper").html(data);
          $('.breadcrumb .active a').attr("href", "#");
          $('.breadcrumb .active a').text(realname);
       }
    });

    $(this).parent().slideUp();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

as you can see on the top, this is a html page type ajax where I send a post key named "page" and its content for example "home" then the server will return the home.html and the contents of my home.html are html tags (divs, a, p, article, h1, h2, h3, h4, section) and a scripts declaration (such as `<script type="application/javascript" src="thispagejavascript.js"></script>`).

Those scripts are necessary for the requested page (e.g. home.html) which run only unto a requested page (e.g. home.html) and create conflict into a current document if declared first so I must only declared it when the requested page is loaded. After response html data (e.g. home html) is received, then it will be put to a div that has an id of "main_content_wrapper".

Problem: everything works except when ajax post request is working, it freezes until the ajax post request is complete and it looks awful because the loading animation freezes too. How can I make the loading animation not freeze until the ajax post request is complete or the page itself?

Any help, clues, ideas, suggestions and recommendations is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `async:true` ! Ensure the page can be correctly displayed without the remove content instead.

Comment: why? i believe I request a big data (html)

Comment: and even without async: true. the page itself still freeze

Comment: Because `async:true` has only one goal: freezing the page. It's even more evil than `eval`.